# How to place iron icons one below another

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to place iron-icon "arrow-drop-up" and "arrow-drop-down" one below another.How do I place it.
Below is what I tried.

```
<div>
<iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-up"></iron-icon>
<iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish make sure that an element is aligned vertically, you can display them as blocks. This can be done very easily:

```
<div>
    <iron-icon style="display:block;" icon="arrow-drop-up"></iron-icon>
    <iron-icon style="display:block;" icon="arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: This will push other elements to next row as well